# Persisting objects with lookup table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is there a way to do the following, without having to first query the database to get my lookup tables objet?

```
$media = new Media();
$doctrine = $this->get('doctrine');

$mediaType = $doctrine->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:MediaType')->findBy(array(
    'name' => 'image'
))[0];

$media  ->setName($name)
        ->setValue($value)
        ->setMediaType($mediaType);

$em = $doctrine->getManager();
$em->persist($media);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would reference you `MediaType` object by its primary key rather than some arbitrary property you could use [`EntityManager::getReference($entityClass, $pk)`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#482-529), but in this situation I believe you have to fetch this entity first.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use the PK - so would that mean my solution is the best approach?